# Stripe not creating customers or charges

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement payment through stripe and i had it working a few weeks ago but now it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using php to implement:

payment.php

```
require('stripe/lib/Stripe.php');

$stripe = array(
'secret_key'      => 'sk_test_???',
'publishable_key' => 'pk_test_???'
);

Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

try{
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
      'card'     => $_POST['stripeToken'],
      'email'    => $_POST['email'],
      'name'     => $_POST['name']
      ));

$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  'card'     => $_POST['stripeToken'],
  'amount'   => 2500,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  "description" => "Charge for ..."
));
} catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
  $errors[] = 'Network problem, perhaps try again.';
} catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
  $errors[] = 'You screwed up in your programming. Shouldnt happen!';
} catch (Stripe_ApiError $e) {
  $errors[] = 'Stripe servers are down!';
} catch (Stripe_CardError $e) {
  $errors[] = 'Card was declined.';
}

echo "<p>You have paid!</p>";
```

register.php

```
<form id="payment-form" action="" method="POST">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_???"
        data-amount="2500"
        data-name="Purtrainer"
        data-description="Monthly Subscription ($25.00)"
    </script>
    <div id="payment-errors">
        <? print_r($errors); ?>
    </div>
    </form>
```

In register.php i have a few text inputs for email, name, password, etc...

When i click the "pay with card" button stripe provides in the js code and i will in the test credit card info, my user gets inputted into my database with al the info from the text inputs, but Strip neither creates the customer nor the charge.

Any help?

Something else to note - going to my payment.php file directly in the URL gives me an error saying there was a problem requiring the stripe file. It says no file exists, even though it does :)

Comment: I'm also facing same problem... Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but on the Stripe dashboard, have you make sured of that you are viewing the Test-data (the slider in the top left). Else: have you checked the JS-console for any errors? Also: remember that Stripe forces your server to have SSL-encryption.

Answer (score 3):

A few things come to mind:

1. The action of the form in *register.php* is local, no to *payment.php*.
2. `data-key="pk_test_???"` should be `$stripe['publishable_key']`
3. As mentioned in the comments SSL is required in live mode, but not in test mode.
4. Check the permissions on all of the files recursively, for testing `chmod -R 777 /path/to/stripe` would be a solid test.
5. Download a fresh copy of the stripe PHP api files.